# Как понять, с какого сайта получил +2?

Tags: поддержка

Отображается уведомление про +2 балла рейтинга, но если развернуть блок уведомлений, там ничего подобного не видно. Понимаю, что подробную историю можно посмотреть в профиле, но... в профиле какого сайта? Не перебирать же все :)

[image: Блок уведомлений]

---

Оказалось, за автоматическое удаление [вопроса](//stackoverflow.com/q/36073970/4928642) на enSO.

Но неужели нет способа это определить кроме перебора сайтов?

Comment: на `en` смотри. и прокрути чуть ниже, что за пункт после "Как проще всего..."?

Comment: @Grundy, не, там не то. Но действительно, с enSO.

Comment: ну как видишь - я сразу сказал :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Тут от некоторых юзеров поступают предложения выкинуть эти уведомления про +1, потому что глаза мозолят, особенно если активно минусовать свежий оффтопик, а вам подробностей зачем-то захотелось...

Comment: Меньше думайте об этих числах )

Comment: А я люблю подробности :)